# JavaScriptによるJSON データの作成とそのデータをJSONデータファイルに追加する方法について

Tags: javascript, json

`data.json`というファイルに対してJSONデータをGETメソッドでリクエストしています。

JavaScript側でJSONデータを作成し、そのデータをリクエスト先のデータファイルに追加するには、どうすれば良いですか？

data.json ファイルの中身

```js
[
  {
    "name": "coco",
    "age": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "puu",
    "age": "4"
  }
]
```

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const requestUrl = "data.json";

request.open("GET", requestUrl);
request.responseType = "json";
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  const cats = request.response;
};
```

Comment: JSONはサーバサイドにあり、Javascriptはブラウザで実行されるのでしょう。であれば、サーバサイドでの処理が必要になりますので、サーバサイドの言語や仕様も合わせて記載してください

Comment: ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。恥ずかしながら、データはサーバーサイド言語で操作するとういうことを、理解できていませんでした。サーバーサイド言語でのデータの取り扱いについて調べて、自分でやってみようと思います。ありがとうございました！